# Why LASSO selects intercept only?

Tags: r, machine-learning, lasso, glmnet, elastic-net

I am doing a projects using `glmnet` package and have hard time to interpret the result.

The scenario as follows.

There are 7 variables x1, ..., x7. 
x3, ... , x7 are scaled to mean 0 and std 1.

I fit a Lasso regression on x3, ... , x7. Lasso selects some variables.

Then I fit a Lasso regression on all variables, i.e., x1, ..., x7, Lasso selects intercept only.

I do not know why this happened and how to fix it.

Comment: can you include a reproducible example in your post?

Comment: hoping you have performed the Lasso regression correctly, the outcome suggests that the model with just the intercept is better than any model that has any of x1,...,x7. The intercept in that model would be the average value of the Y, meaning that predicting the outcome as average value of Y has less error than any model that includes x1,...x7